# Keyboard stops working in Boot menu

Tags: windows-7

My keyboard doesnt respond when im in "boot menu". Works everywhere else, inside bios settings too

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to turn on legacy usb support in bios.

Answer (score 0):

First of all is your keyboard PS/2 or USB?

- Try to unplug and replug the keyboard during the boot sequence
- Try a different keyboard
- or Turn in Legacy USB support in your Bios (but I dont really know how you're gonna do that if your keyboard is malfunctioning)

Answer (score 0):

In the Bios Setup, change LEGACY USB SUPPORT to ENABLED.

If the keyb doesn't work in the Bios Setup, try with a PS2 keyb, change this option and then connect the USB Keyb  (you are suppose to power off the computer for disconnection a PS2 device)

If when windows starts the keyb doesn't work, don't power off, wait at least 10 minutes, because windows is re-recognizing the keyb again, and is installing the driver.